# External hard drive gets slower after the first few transferred GB and takes minutes to unmount

Tags: ubuntu

I am using a Usb3 external Toshiba Canvio hard drive with a Dell Latitude running Ubuntu.

I used the hard drive without any problem whatsoever for about a week: great read and write performances (around 100MB/s).

Today I connect it again and without no apparent reason something strange happens: it begins writing data at around 200MB/s, then after 2 or 3 GB it slows down to 10-20MB/s or even less and continues like this.
When I try to unmount it, it takes more than a minute or two to stop spinning and performing the unmount.
As it is it became almost useless.

I tried to update my computer's bios, and to clear the hidden folders on the external hard drive.
Any suggestion about what may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal operation inside the hard drive there is a cache that can be written to at much faster speeds then can actually be written to the spinning platters.  Under most operations the cache is large enough to handle everything and you do not notice anything but when a large file or multiple smaller files are copied that cache gets filled up and you are slowed down to the speed that can actually be written to the platters.  When you attempt to unmount the drive any data that hasn't been written to the disk must be completed before it can be unmounted that is why there is the delay.

There is also noticeable differences on write speeds depending on whether they are sequential or not.  There has been may articles about this issue I will try to find one and leave the link for you if your interested in reading a more en depth explanation.

Comment: Thank you. It seems then that I had only the impression that the disk was performing better.